# Under what conditions i will need more entity managers in symfony2 Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been using symfony2 and doctrine2. I am working with one entity manager.

I am still not able to find why would there be need of more entity managers in project.

Can anyone please explain me what is the use case of having more entity managers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can use multiple entity managers in a Symfony2 application. This is necessary if you are using different databases or even vendors with entirely different sets of entities. In other words, one entity manager that connects to one database will handle some entities while another entity manager that connects to another database might handle the rest.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: i am using one database , so it means i don't have to worry about more entity managers

Comment: Not necessarily.  Another potentiality major reason for needing multiple entity managers is that when an entity manager throws an exception (perhaps a constraint violation) then that entity manager can no longer be used.  So if you wanted to log the exception or do anything else with the database then you need a second independent entity manager.

Answer (score 1):

You need more than one entity manager if you want to connect to multiple databases.

Moreover, if you want to use Doctrine PHPCR or Doctrine OXM, you have to use their respective entity manager.